# Combo box dependiente no carga al editar y el nombre del la foto no se recupera en su campo

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Mi combo box al añadir nuevo registro funciona bien su dependencia pero al editar no carga la subcategoria o el segundo combo, se queda vacio y si lo guardo asi vacio me guarda null el valor, la unica forma de activar o volver a seleccionar es cambianado el 1er combo y recien carga el segundo y tambien el nombre de mi foto no carga para editarlo o volverlo a cargar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
 $('.showdata').on('click', '.item-edit', function(){
                        var id = $(this).attr('data');
                        $('#myModal').modal('show');
                        $('#myModal').find('.modal-title').text('Editar Producto');
                        $('#myForm').attr('action', '<?php echo base_url() ?>producto/updateProduct');
                        $.ajax({
                                type: 'ajax',
                                method: 'get',
                                url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>producto/editProduct',
                                data: {id: id},
                                async: false,
                                dataType: 'json',
                                success: function(data){
                                    $('select[name=txtId]').val(data.cat_id);
                                    $('select[name=txtSubId]').val(data.sub_id);    
                                    $('input[name=txtCodigo]').val(data.pr_codigo);
                                    $('input[name=txtProducto]').val(data.pr_nombre);
                                    $('textarea[name=txtDescripcion]').val(data.pr_descripcion);
                                    $('input[name=txtProdId]').val(data.pr_id);
                                    $('input[name=txtCantidad]').val(data.pr_cantidad_stock);
                                    $('input[name=txtCatalogo]').val(data.pr_precio_catalogo);
                                    $('input[name=txtOferta]').val(data.pr_precio_oferta);


                    $('input[name=txtFoto]').val(data.pr_foto);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('No se puede editar el Registro');
                }
            });
        });

$(document).ready(function () {

            $.getJSON('<?php echo base_url() ?>employee/showAllEmployee', function (data) {
                var items = '<option value="" selected="" disabled="">-- Elija una Categoria --</option>';
                $.each(data, function (name, value) {

                    items += "<option value='" + value.cat_id + "'>" + value.cat_nombre + "</option>";
                });
                $("#categoria").html(items);

                $('#categoria').change(function () {
                    var cat = $('#categoria').val();
                    //subcat(cat);
                     $.getJSON('<?php echo base_url() ?>subcategoria/showAllSubCat', {id: cat}, function (data) {

                    var items = '<option value="" selected="" disabled="">-- Elija una Subcategoria --</option>';
                    $.each(data, function (name, value) {

                        items += "<option value='" + value.sub_id + "'>" + value.sub_nombre + "</option>";
                    });
                    $("#subcategoria").html(items);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

            <form id="myForm" action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <input type="hidden" name="txtProdId" value="0">
                        <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="category" class="label-control col-md-4">Nombre categoría</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <select class="form-control col-md-4" for="name" name="txtId" id="categoria"> 
                        </select>
                        </div>
                </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="subcategory" class="label-control col-md-4">Nombre subcategoría</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <select class="form-control col-md-4" for="name" name="txtSubId" id="subcategoria"> 
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="codig" class="label-control col-md-4">Codigo</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input type="text" name="txtCodigo" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="label-control col-md-4">Nombre Producto</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input type="text" name="txtProducto" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="description" class="label-control col-md-4">Descripción</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="txtDescripcion"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="txtFoto" class="label-control col-md-4">Imagen</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input type="file" name="txtFoto"  id="txtFoto">
                    </div>
                </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cant" class="label-control col-md-4">Cantidad</label>
                        <label for="catalog" class="label-control col-md-4">Precio catálogo</label>
                        <label for="ofert" class="label-control col-md-4">Precio oferta</label>
                </div>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div>
                                <input type="text" name="txtCantidad" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                                <span class="input-group-addon">-</span>
                            <div>
                                <input type="text" name="txtCatalogo" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                                <span class="input-group-addon">-</span>
                            <div>
                                <input type="text" name="txtOferta" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <button type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: Revisa mediante la consola del navegador que tengas el valor que necesitas del combobox... a lo mejor si lo tienes pero el texto como tal no lo tienes asignado...

Comment: en consola si recupera lo que necesito, el problema esta en mostrarlo o que se recupere en el combo box sin necesidad de cambiar el primer combobox

Comment: Entonces solo forza el texto con `.text()` si es que te recupera el value correctamente

Comment: O crea un combobox partiendo de lo que obtienes de respuesta con append, eso se me ocurriria

Comment: No soy experto en java script pero me gustaria que me den una idea de mas o menos como resolver lo del combobox...

Comment: Puedes utilizar para un primer caso `$('#categoria').val(data.cat_id).trigger('change');` seria un ejemplo para cambiar, mediante un **trigger**

Comment: con lo del trigger si se puede cargar la segunda lista pero aun no muestra la subcategoria elegida solo se habilita pa seleccionar una..

Comment: revisaste que el valor se cargue en el **select**? si es así ahora solo forza el texto con `.text()`, es decir, del valor obtenido de la categoria busca su texto y asignaselo directamente al **select** esto solo si   tienes el valor en el segundo **select** y ya cuando te guarda ese campo deberia no enviarte un null.

Comment: `$('input[name=txtFoto]').val(data.pr_foto);` esta es la forma de mostrar el nombre de archivo en el campo input file ?